# Difference between Android.R resources class and local Resources class

Tags: java, android

> android:id = "android:id/empty"
>
> With the android package namespace in place, we're now referencing an ID from the android.R resources class, rather than the local resources class.

Above is what's been written down in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html, when we set a View object's id like this, what does that mean we are referencing from android.R but not local resources class? What is local resources class? is it R.java? if so what's the difference between R.java and android.R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android.R - resources from Android SDK.
R. - resources created in your project.
```

Comment: we when we use android:id = "android:id/empty" we are not referencing an object's id in our R.java file, but one already existed in the resources from the SDK?

Comment: yes, if your type ```android:``` prefix, the value referencing on resource(id/drawable/layout etc) from Android SDK